# Skip requiring a module for tests in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tap

moduleOne:

```
const moduleTwo = require('moduleTwo'); //moduleTwo opens Websocket
module.exports = {
  functionToTest: () => 1
}
```

Now i want to test that function - test.js:

```
const tap = require('tap');
const moduleOne = require('moduleOne');

tap.equal(moduleOne.functionToTest(),1);
```

The problem is, that in moduleTwo some code is run that opens a websocket  and the test does not finish.

How do i prevent moduleOne of requiring moduleTwo while testing?

Comment: inside moduleOne exports, add some option to decide if you want to require moduleTwo or not. Then when you require moduleOne you pass it some options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mock-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require):

```
const tap = require('tap');
mock('moduleTwo', {
    // export whatever you need, just don't open websockets
});
// now moduleOne will require your mock instead of real moduleTwo
const moduleOne = require('moduleOne');
tap.equal(moduleOne.functionToTest(),1);
```

Or you can add some options to `moduleTwo` but it will require changing every place where it is used.